# Doubt about Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-transformations, self-learning

A linear transformation $T:V->W$ is surjective if $Range(T)=W$.
Now let A and B be two vector spaces such that A is a subspace of B and $dim(A)=dim(B)$ ; we can say that $A=B$.
So from this can we say that T is surjective only when $dim(Range(T))=dim(W)$ because Range(T) is a subspace of W ?

Comment: That is all correct. You should also indicate what your question is.  And just don’t title questions “Doubt in/of/about blahblah”. Nobody likes that.

Comment: We should note that all of this assumes we're talking about _finite dimensional_ vector spaces; if the spaces are allowed  to have infinite dimension it's easy to give examples where $A$ is a subspace of $B$, $\dim(A)=\dim(B)$ but $A\ne B$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have a finite-dimensional vector space $\textsf V$ and $\textsf W \subseteq \textsf V$ a subspace of it, then :
$$\begin{matrix}
\dim (\textsf W) < \dim (\textsf V) & \Leftrightarrow & \textsf W \subsetneq \textsf V \\
\dim (\textsf W) = \dim (\textsf V) & \Leftrightarrow & \textsf W = \textsf V
\end{matrix}$$

Comment: I have corrected "subspace of him" into "subspace of it"